# Even Odd problem

Tags: algorithms

"A" represents all the odd natural numbers and "B" represents all the even natural numbers. For a given integer v, we can reduce it either by A0 or (A0)+1 then B0 or (B0)+1 and so on until the value of v becomes <=0. Considering that we chose (Ai) or (Ai)+1 and (Bi) or (Bi)+1 optimally where i is the index, we want to know whether the last reduced value is from set A or B.

For example if v=1 or v=2, the answer will be A but for v=3 answer will be B.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.  I don't know what it means to reduce it by A0.  Can you think about how to explain the question in a way where you define all your terms?  It would help to use mathematics to define the problem carefully.  Also, is this a question about computer science?  It looks to me like it might be purely a question about mathematics, not computer science.

Comment: A0 means the first element of the even natural numbers set which is 1 and B0 is 2.

Comment: @3xpl017 But $1$ is odd, not even. So why is $1$ in $A$ if $A$ is the set of *even* natural numbers ??

Comment: Sorry, meant A is the set of odd numbers

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce"? Subtraction, perhaps? Later, what do you mean by "optimally"? What are you optimizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can phrase the question in game playing terms as follows:

Starting from some positive integer value $v$, players $A$ and $B$ take it in turn to subtract numbers until the running total is equal to or less than $0$. On their first turn player $A$ may subtract $1$ or $2$; then player $B$ may subtract $2$ or $3$, then player $A$ may subtract $3$ or $4$ and so on. The player who makes the final move, making the running total less than or equal to $0$, wins. With optimal play from both $A$ and $B$, which player wins for a given value of $v$ ?

Here is an approach this problem:

1. The running total after $1$ turn is $v-1$ or $v-2$. The running total after $2$ turns is $v-3$, $v-4$ or $v-5$. Show that the running total after $n$ terms lies between $v-T_n$ and $v-T_{n+1}+1$, where $T_n$ is the nth triangular number (the sum of $1 \dots n$).
2. Suppose $T_n \le v < T_{n+1}$. If $n$ is even show that $A$ will want to maximise the running total after $n$ turns and so will always choose to subtract the lower value on their turn; whereas $B$ will want to minimise the running total after $n$ turns and so will always choose to subtract the higher value on their turn. If $n$ is odd show that the strategies are reversed; $A$ will always choose to subtract the higher value and $B$ will always choose to subtract the lower value.
3. Show that if both players follow their optimal strategy as described in (2) then the running total after $n$ turns is $v-\frac{n^2+2n}{2}$ if $n$ is even or $v-\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}$ if $n$ is odd.
4. Show that $B$ will win if $2m^2+1 \le v \le 2m^2+2m$ for some integer $m$ and $A$ will win otherwise.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted to ask :), sorry could not explain it properly.